# pseudo :after element not lining up with parent

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to use the `:after` psuedo-element to create an inwards arrow effect on table cells.

It's working, except that the `:after` element doesn't always align with its parent element.

In the [example I've put together](https://jsfiddle.net/p1r4dzfL/), you can see that the right-hand borders of the `th`s labelled 4, 5, 6, and 7 line up with their `:after` element, but that the right-hand borders of 1, 2, and 3 don't.

Why does this occur? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: it is a matter of calculation in between number of cells, border-spacing + width . example https://jsfiddle.net/p1r4dzfL/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/p1r4dzfL/2/  ... also padding/box-sizing ...

Comment: Oh, that was much simpler than I was making it out to be, thanks!

Comment: you could also only set width of column/cells to make pseudo match https://jsfiddle.net/p1r4dzfL/3/

Comment: So why do the spare pixels get taken out from the middle of the element, and not from either the beginning or the end?